# How to highlight all matches using a backreference?

Tags: regex, search, vim, match

I have this:

`/\(\d\{4}_\d\{2}_\d\{2}\).*\1`

to find double dates in the same line.

I would like to highlight (as in a normal search) all matches found (not only the first one as in above regex).

How can I do this?

Comment: What causes it to hightlight? The capturing parens? Have you tried putting parens around the `\1`? (I would have thought the whole match would be highlighted.)

Comment: @KennethK. It highlights the matches and all between. I want it to highlight only the dates.

Comment: Highlighting only the dates would require a Vim option telling it to ignore the first match in every line. (You would search only for a simple date pattern then, so a single match matches only a single date.) But AFAIK, such an option does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Vim](http://www.vim.org), I gather from the question tags. In Vim, activate [hlsearch](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27hlsearch%27):

```
:set hlsearch
```

Then search like this:

```
/\d\{4}_\d\{2}_\d\{2}[^0-9]*\d\{4}_\d\{2}_\d\{2}
```

This highlights all double dates in a line in the entire file. The regex assumes that the space between the dates is filled by characters which are not numbers.

Illustration of the regex:
[image: Illustration of the regex]

Comment: Where did you get this image from? I love those little robots working with digits ;-)

Comment: @Thomas, I want to highlight only the matches. Your solutions highlights the matches and all between.

Comment: @Remonn Well, that is impossible, because Vim always highlights the *match*, and a match is defined by the regex, so it highlights everything that matches, including the space in between. You could drop the "double date" requirement and simply highlight all dates though.

Comment: @Thomas highlighting all dates highlights even the dates which do not have a double in the same row.

Comment: @Remonn Exactly, but those are your choices, I'm afraid.